# Authentication Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I am using 1.0.0-beta4.1 Azure Java SDK. This is my code for authentication

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String client = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String tenant = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String key = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client, tenant, key, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
    System.out.println("Listing all resource groups");
```

The code doesn't throw any error in case of incorrect credentials. 
Is there any way to find whether the authentication was successful or not.

Comment: The current hack I am applying is to check the class variables of "azure" object is null or not and based on that deduce whether the authentication was successful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, it seems that missing some required methods which include [`configure()`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/Azure.html#configure--), please see below.

```
Azure azure = Azure.configure()  // Initial an Azure.Configurable object
                   .withLogLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC)
                   .authenticate(credentials)
                   .withSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

Please try to use the code above instead of yours. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now it throws an exception in case of incorrect credentials.

Comment: What is the Jar version you are using to run this application. Am unable to use withLogLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC), getting the following compile time error :The method withLogLevel(LogLevel) in the type AzureConfigurable<Azure.Configurable> is not applicable for the arguments (HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same exception and I was able to resolve it by replacing HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC **with** LogLevel.BASIC.

Aso, I would like to inform that I used the dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```